# Totality of a family in $L^2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $I=[0,1]$. For $n\in\mathbb N$, define the function $f_n$ as
$$f_n(x) = \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n}\,.$$
Is the family $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ total in $L^2(I)$, i.e., is the closure of the span of the family $\{f_n\}$ the whole $L^2(I)$?

I would say yes, but I'm not sure about how to show it. Any hint about where to start from?

Comment: $\|f_n\|_2 \to 0$ so there is no chance for the sequence to be dense.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy True, actually the question is ill posed, I'm interested in the linear span...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set is total if and only if  the only function orthogonal to every function in it $0$. Suppose $f \in L^{2}$ and $\int f(x)f_n(x)dx=0$ for all $n \geq 1$. Let $g(x)=\frac {f(x)} {1+x^{2}}$ Then $\int g(x)f_n(x)dx=0$ for all $n \geq 0$. Linear combinations of the functions $\{f_n: n \geq 0\}$ form an algebra which contains constants and separates points. By Stone-Weierstrass Theorem this algebra is dense in $C[0,1]$. I will let you finish the proof.

Comment: Thank you! Now I see how to conclude.